# How to add a clickable component icon within a form input using react

Tags: reactjs

I want to integrate a giy option as apart of the comment form, this is what i have so far.

[image]

For example, discord form section.

[image]

Upon clicking gif option, a gif component is rendered and user can select a gif and add it as a comment.

How would i achieve this using react ? Here is the comment form component.

**commentForm**

```
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";

const CommentForm = (props) => (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
      <TextField
        type="text"
        style={{ borderRadius: "50%" }}
        id="outlined-multiline-static"
        label="Write A Comment"
        multiline={true}
        name="comment_body"
        value={props.commentBody}
        rows="3"
        fullWidth={true}
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={props.commentChange}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Button type="submit" variant="outlined" color="primary">
        Post A Comment
     </Button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
export default CommentForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out by looking into it more. Just need to add inputProps to comment form.

referring to this example

https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#icons

Like this

```
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import React from "react";
import GifIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Gif';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
const CommentForm = (props) => (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
      <TextField
        type="text"
        style={{ borderRadius: "50%" }}
        id="outlined-multiline-static"
        label="Write A Comment"
        multiline={true}
        name="comment_body"
        value={props.commentBody}
        rows="3"
        fullWidth={true}
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="start">
              <GifIcon onClick={() => console.log('test')}/>
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={props.commentChange}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Button type="submit" variant="outlined" color="primary">
        Post A Comment
     </Button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
export default CommentForm;
```